Quasicoherent sheaves on relative Spec
Vakil's Foundations of Algebraic Geometry, exercise 17.1.E.
Let $X$ be a scheme, and $\mathcal{R}$ be a sheaf of $O_X$-algebras (edit: assume $\mathcal{R}$ is quasicoherent). Show that the category of quasicoherent sheaves on $\underline{Spec}_X(\mathcal{R})$ is equivalent to the category of
quasicoherent sheaves on $X$ with the structure of $\mathcal{R}$-modules (quasicoherent $\mathcal{R}$-modules on $X$). Show that the category of finite type quasicoherent sheaves on
$\underline{Spec}_X(\mathcal{R})$ is equivalent to the category of quasicoherent sheaves on $X$ with the structure of “finite type” $\mathcal{R}$-modules (finite type quasicoherent $\mathcal{R}$-modules on X).
I'm not sure what "quasicoherent $\mathcal{R}$-modules" means. I think it means sheaf of $\mathcal{R}$-modules that is quasicoherent as a sheaf of $O_X$-modules.
Now to prove the theorem : Let $F$ be a quasicoherent sheaf of $\mathcal{R}$-modules and $U \subseteq X$ be an affine open set, and $f : \underline{Spec}_X(\mathcal{R}) \rightarrow X$ be the canonical morphism. The scalar multiplication map is an $\mathcal{R}(U)$-module structure on $F(U)$, so I think on $f^{-1}(U)$, we take $\widetilde{F(U)}$.
I think I need to glue the sheaves next. Let $U, V \subseteq X$ be affine open sets. I need to find an isomorphism $\widetilde{F(U)}|_{f^{-1}(U \cap V)} \simeq \widetilde{F(V)}|_{f^{-1}(U \cap V)}$. The problem is that $X$ might not be separated, so $U \cap V$ might not be affine. I can cover $U \cap V$ with affine open sets $W_i$ and get an isomorphism there, but then again, I don't know how to show that the isomorphisms glue.
I also tried to describe the quasicoherent sheaf on $\underline{Spec}_X(\mathcal{R})$ without using affine opens. I tried $f^* F$ but that didn't work out since if $X$ is affine, $f^* F$ corresponds to tensor product, which isn't an equivalence of categories.
How can I prove this theorem?

You need to add the assumption that $\mathcal{R}$ is quasi-coherent. Question: do you know how this works when $X$ is affine?

@MartinBrandenburg If $X = Spec(A)$ is affine then it's just $\widetilde{F(X)}$, where $F(X)$ is a $\mathcal{R}(X)$-module, right?
